# Error running Gradle, gradlew.bat exited abnormally, A problem occurred evaluating project

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have tried many times to create a signin and signup page using firebase authentication but I have been recieving such errors. Initially i was able to build the layout (of form) successfully but the id and pass are not registered in firebase and I recieve such errors. I have been stuck here since days, please help. Thanks

android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with 
flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = 
localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = 
localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.login"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` 
works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
}

flutter {
source '../..'
} 

dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error-
Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1803 in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Happy\code\login\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Happy\code\login\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > ASCII
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 34s
  Command: C:\Users\Happy\code\login\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is just go to your project level build and change your classpath dependencies as below.

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21"
```

This might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Lowering Google Services to 4.2.0 in android/build.gradle should do the job, not more nor less.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```